# Correct way to stop Leaflet Map propagation

Tags: leaflet, mapping

What is the correct use of the Leaflet `stopPropagation`?

I have a canvas map drawn with some custom png markers. That works great, but when they are clicked, both the marker and map click events are fired. I just want the marker click event to fire.

https://francoisromain.github.io/leaflet-markers-canvas/dist/leaflet-markers-canvas.js to do the custom canvas png markers.

```
     var marker = L.marker([entry.Lat, entry.Lon], {icon: icon, UniqueId: entry.UniqueId}).on('click', onClick).bindTooltip(entry.Callsign);
 aircraftmarkers.addMarker(marker);
```

The below function is when a marker is clicked.

```
function onClick(e) { /*show the div*/ }
```

And this is the function for when the map (not marker) is clicked.

```
map.on('click', function(e) { /*hide the div*/}
```

So as you can tell when I click the marker, it would show and hide the div at the same time.
I have tried putting in

```
L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e).
```

to either and both of the functions but this does not seem to make any difference whatsoever.

From the console I can tell that the marker event is fired, then the map event, presumably due to the order of layers.

What is the correct use of the `stopPropagation()`? Am I missing something? On Leaflet 1.7.1

Here is the full onClick(e)

```
 function onClick(e) {
 L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);

    //////////////////set the currentselectedmarker variable.
    currentselectedmarker = this.options.UniqueId;
    
    //////////////////set marker id in url
    window.history.replaceState('', this.options.Callsign+' - Live Map', '?id='+currentselectedmarker);
    ///////////////ensure only 1 request can happen per second
    if (((Date.now() / 1000) - lastwindowupdate) > 1) {
    lastwindowupdate = Date.now() / 1000;
    map.panTo(this.getLatLng());
    document.getElementById("searchresults").innerHTML = '';
    
    if (screen.width > 600) {
    /////////////screen width is large enough for normal window, show it
    document.getElementById("window").style.width = "335px";
    document.getElementById("window").innerHTML = '<br><br><center><img height="250px" width="300px" src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/leaflet/loading.gif"></center>';
    $('#window').load('<?php echo site_url(); ?>/leaflet/livemapaircraft.php?id='+this.options.UniqueId, function() {
    });
    }
    else {
    /////////////screen width is too small, show the mobile window instead
    document.getElementById("window-mobile").style.height = "170px";
    document.getElementById("window-mobile").innerHTML = '<center><img height="150px" width="200px" src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/leaflet/loading.gif"></center>';
    $('#window-mobile').load('<?php echo site_url(); ?>/leaflet/livemapaircraft-mobile.php?id='+this.options.UniqueId, function() {
    });
        
    }
  
    }
    
    
    ////////reqeust too early
    }
```

Comment: You write that you have tried, but didn't include code of how you have tried. Please include also that code. But it definitely should be `L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e)`.

Comment: Thank for your reply I have added the entire onClick(e) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are out of luck here with regular standard solutions, since [leaflet-markers-canvas](https://francoisromain.github.io/leaflet-markers-canvas/) plugin somehow messes with regular Leaflet event processing. Neither `L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e)` or `L.DomEvent.preventDefault(e)` prevent click event reaching the map.

One possible solution would be to have marker click indicator `markerClick` and set it to `true` when marker is clicked. It can be used then to skip map click processing.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var markerClicked = false;

function onClick(e) {
  markerClicked = true;
.
.
.
}

map.on('click', function(e) {
  if (markerClicked) {
    markerClicked = false;
    return;
  }
.
.
.  
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the comment. I thought this may be the case. What I have done is got my code to record the timestamp the marker and map click events are fired, and only allowing the map event to fire if it is over 1 second since the marker click. This does not stop it from firing but at least I have control whether my code is executed. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Sequence of events is always: first marker click event in then map click event. This means there is no need for timestamps and for 1 second gap when map click event is not allowed.